# Rails 4: deciding which inherited child class to use in parent class initializer

Tags: class, inheritance, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Report class that several models inherit from (OverviewReport, CategoryReport, etc...).  Each of these inherited classes has specific methods/attributes that need to be customized for that type of report.

The desired report type is passed in via the params hash, so I can do something like the following:

```
# reports_controller.rb
def index
  case params[:type]
    when "overview" then OverviewReport.new(...)
    when "category" then CategoryReport.new(...)
    ...etc...
  end
end
```

This works, but I would like to clean up the controller a little bit.  I would like to be able to do this:

```
# reports_controller.rb
def index
  @report = Report.new(params[:type], ...)
end

# report.rb class
def initialize(type, options)
  case type
    when "overview" then self = OverviewReport.new(type, options)
    when "category" then self = CategoryReport.new(type, options)
  end
end
```

However, you can't change the value of `self`, so how would you go about accomplishing this functionality?

The intent is the clean up the controller code and abstract away which report you're using, so I can call `@report.some_method()` and it will call the inherited-specific method.

Is there a clean solution to this, or am I stuck with a (somewhat) lengthy case statement in my controller?

One solution would be to use a "factory" class whose sole purpose is to instantiate the correct class:

```
# reports_controller.rb
def index
  @report = AgnosticReport.new(type)
end

# agnostic_report.rb
def initialize(type)
  case type
    when "overview" then return OverviewReport.new(type)
    when "category" then return CategoryReport.new(type)
    ...etc...
  end
end
```

This is perfectly acceptable, but I was wondering if there was any need to add a "third" layer of classes to this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the ability to change the type params passed?

If so I would use [constantize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-constantize)

params[:type] being "Overview Report" or "Category Report" e.t.c.

then use 
@report = params[:type].constantize.new

s = "OverviewReport",

s.constantize => OverviewReport

Comment: that's a very interesting solution; I knew RoR had the ability to dynamically convert text to code, but I never thought about using that in this situation. It's a viable solution but I'll have to perform some logic to ensure the params are being passed in properly formatted, etc...

Comment: Yes there is that.  But you still have that issue with using a case statement in your controller